# Error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, parseint

I am receiving the following error when running my code.

> error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to JTextField

JGrasp is pointing to the following as the issue.

> Programming6_4.Java:143: error: incompatible types: double cannot be
>   converted to JTextField
>               averageScoreTF = (test1 * wght1 + test2 * wght2 + test3 * wght3 + test4 * wght4);
>                                                                              ^
>   1 error

Not sure why it is flagging the '+' as the item that cannot be converted.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

   public class Programming6_4 extends JFrame
   {
      //declares variables
      private JLabel blankGrid1L, blankGrid2L, blankGrid3L, scoreL, weightL, testOneL, testTwoL, testThreeL, testFourL, averageScoreL;

      private JTextField  testOneTF, testTwoTF, testThreeTF, testFourTF, testOnewTF, testTwowTF, testThreewTF, testFourwTF, averageScoreTF;

      private JButton calculateScoreB, exitB;

      private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;

      private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

      //declare window size
      private static final int WIDTH = 400;
      private static final int HEIGHT = 200;

      public Programming6_4()
      {
         //name labels
         blankGrid1L = new JLabel ("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         blankGrid2L = new JLabel ("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         blankGrid3L = new JLabel ("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         scoreL = new JLabel ("Score", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         weightL = new JLabel ("Weight", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         testOneL = new JLabel ("Test One Score: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         testTwoL = new JLabel ("Test Two Score: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         testThreeL = new JLabel ("Test Three Score: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         testFourL = new JLabel ("Test Four Score: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
         averageScoreL = new JLabel ("Average Weighted Test Score: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

         //create text fields 10 characters - Test Scores
         testOneTF = new JTextField(10);
         testTwoTF = new JTextField(10);
         testThreeTF = new JTextField(10);
         testFourTF = new JTextField(10);

         //create text fields 10 charaters - Weights
         testOnewTF = new JTextField(10);
         testTwowTF = new JTextField(10);
         testThreewTF = new JTextField(10);
         testFourwTF = new JTextField(10);
         averageScoreTF = new JTextField(10);

         //create buttons and handler
         calculateScoreB = new JButton ("Calculate");
         cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
         calculateScoreB.addActionListener(cbHandler);

         exitB = new JButton ("Exit");
         ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
         exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

         //set grid size
         Container pane = getContentPane();
         pane.setLayout(new GridLayout (7, 3));

         //add elements to grid spaced by line
         pane.add (blankGrid1L);
         pane.add (scoreL);
         pane.add (weightL);

         pane.add (testOneL);
         pane.add (testOneTF);
         pane.add (testOnewTF);

         pane.add (testTwoL);
         pane.add (testTwoTF);
         pane.add (testTwowTF);

         pane.add (testThreeL);
         pane.add (testThreeTF);
         pane.add (testThreewTF);

         pane.add (testFourL);
         pane.add (testFourTF);
         pane.add (testFourwTF);

         pane.add (averageScoreL);
         pane.add (averageScoreTF);
         pane.add (blankGrid2L);

         pane.add (calculateScoreB);
         pane.add (blankGrid3L);
         pane.add (exitB);

         //set window title, window, and display
         setTitle ("Weighted Test Average Calculation");
         setSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
         setVisible (true);
         setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         //setLayout (new Programming6_4());
      }
         //activates ActionListener
      private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener

         //Main calculation program
      {
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)  //public static void main (String[] args)
         {
            //declare varibles in 
            double test1, test2, test3, test4, wght1, wght2, wght3, wght4, avgscore /*avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4*/;

            //takes text entered by user and converts from string to decimal
            test1 = Double.parseDouble(testOneTF.getText());
            wght1 = Double.parseDouble(testOnewTF.getText());
            test2 = Double.parseDouble(testTwoTF.getText());
            wght2 = Double.parseDouble(testTwowTF.getText());
            test3 = Double.parseDouble(testThreeTF.getText());
            wght3 = Double.parseDouble(testThreewTF.getText());
            test4 = Double.parseDouble(testFourTF.getText());
            wght4 = Double.parseDouble(testFourwTF.getText());

            //calculations needed to get weighted average
            //avg1 = test1 * wght1;
            //avg2 = test2 * wght2;
            //avg3 = test3 * wght3;
            //avg4 = test4 * wght4;
            //avgscore = avg1 + avg2 + avg3 + avg4;

            averageScoreTF = (test1 * wght1 + test2 * wght2 + test3 * wght3 + test4 * wght4);
            averageScoreTF.setText("" + avgscore);
         }
      }

      private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
         {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
               {
                  System.exit(0);
               }
         }

      public static void maine (String[]args)
         {
            Programming6_4 testObject = new Programming6_4();
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this lines:

```
averageScoreTF = (test1 * wght1 + test2 * wght2 + test3 * wght3 + test4 * wght4);
```

to:

```
avgscore = (test1 * wght1 + test2 * wght2 + test3 * wght3 + test4 * wght4);
```

You cannot assign a double to `averageScoreTF` since `averageScoreTF` is not a numeric type (just like the error message said).

Comment: That did it, I have looked at it for a couple of hours trying to find it. A simple typing error, I should have caught that. I am very new at this, 6 weeks new. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You clearly are confused - a double is a number, a jtextfield is a GUI widget. 
Most likely you want to print your number into a text field for presentation.

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly put the jtext field in the place of the double I declared.